# Ember.js Create an array with one of the properties of the model in the controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have got a model like this:

```
App.Topology = DS.Model.extend({
name: DS.attr('string'),
sites: DS.attr()
});
```

And in the view I would like to make a select with all the names. For that I should have in the controller an array with all this names in order to do:

```
{{view Ember.Select content=ArrayThatIneed}}
```

How could I create this array in the controller?

```
App.PanelRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function(){
    return this.store.find('topology');
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an computed property to provide the array with the names:

```
App.PanelController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  names: function() {
    return this.get('content').map(function(topology) {
      return topology.get('name');
    });
  }.property('content')
})
```

And use it like this:

```
{{view Ember.Select content=names}}
```

Or you could use the attributes of the select to display the correct information. This will also allow you to use the selected topology in the controller for further use.

```
{{view Ember.Select
       content=controller
       optionLabelPath="content.name"
       selection=selectedTopology}}
```

Comment: So controller inside the helper in the view refers to the controller in use? That helps a lot, thank you very much.

Comment: With the second option selection is <App.Topology:ember411:1> (which is the id), how could I retrieve the name?

Comment: Add another attribute to set the value of the options: `optionValuePath="content.name"`

Comment: selectedTopology is still <App.Topology:ember411:1>, I didn't want to say the option selection but the selectedTopology variable, sorry

Comment: Hmm, I'm afraid you then have to use `selectedTopology.get('name')` in your controller. Maybe you find another solution here: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Select.html

Comment: I thought that, but (this.get('selectedTopology')).get('name') doesn't work, do you know why?

Comment: Ok, it's because the default value its not working in this case (the second you showed) and I don't know why

Comment: Do you have the default value set in the controller?

Comment: Yes, selectedTopology: 'OneTopology'. It's working if I use the first solution but not with the second, and I dont understand well this of the 'content' stuff, so I prefer the second one